# Are QC-codes really quasi-cyclic?

Tags: error-correction, qkd

The definition of quasi-cyclic codes is that there is a constant $l$
such that a codeword right-shifted by $l$ positions is still a valid
codeword. (defined e.g. in https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/quasi_cyclic)

The definition of QC-block codes (where QC-LDPC are just QC-block codes with a sparse density matrix) is presented as codes having the parity check matrix made up of circulant submatrices. (As defined e.g. in https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4129)

Formally: Let $J, I,$ and $r$ be positive integers. Let a $Jr\times Ir$ matrix $H$ be the parity-check matrix of a block code. If it is of the form

$$\boldsymbol{H} = \begin{pmatrix}H_{0,0} & H_{0,1} & \cdots & H_{0, I-1} \\\\
H_{1,0} & H_{1,1} & \cdots & H_{1, I-1} \\\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\ 
H_{J-1,0} & H_{J-1,1} & \cdots & H_{J-1, I-1} \end{pmatrix},$$

with each $r\times r$ submatrix $H_{j,i}$ of the PCM being circulant, we call the LDPC code *quasi-cylic*.

In the article https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4129 they proceed to state that

> Such a code
> is called quasi-cyclic (QC) because applying circular shifts to
> length-$r$ sub-blocks of a codeword gives a codeword again.

How should I interpret this statement? I take from it that if I apply the same circular shift to all the $r$ bit subblocks (out of $I$) in the codeword, I get another codeword. That is definitely true, one can easily see that. However, it is incompatible with the definition of quasi-cyclic codes above as it does not guarantee that there is an $l$ fro the whole codeword. And it seems to me that indeed, for some QC-block codes no such $l$ exists.